# Why does Parse.Config return undefined?

Tags: parse-platform

Recently Parse.com has announced the Parse.Config feature. However, in cloud code, trying to access Parse.Config always returns undefined.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("search", function(req, res) {
    Parse.Config.get().then(function(config) { 
        // This line is never reached.
    });
}
```

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Cloud Code is probably running with an older version of the SDK that does not yet support Parse Config.

You can set the version of the SDK to use as follows:

1. Open a terminal, cd into the directory of your project
2. Run `parse jssdk 1.3.0`
3. Re-delpoy your code

This will set the SDK version your code uses to v1.3.0 of the Parse JavaScript SDK and Parse Config should work then.

Comment: So the command reconfigs my Parse cloud environment under the hood? I am just curious.

Comment: Yes that is basically it. The Cloud Code runs against the SDK version that was the most current one when you first deployed it. This is kind of useful as it will not break your code by automatically updating the version, just in case the release included breaking changes. You can also switch back any time, it is well documented here https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#clt

Comment: I'm still having this issue with sdk 1.6. I'm using `heroku` as the host for my cloud code, could it be related to this? I keep having a `unauthorized` error...

Answer (score 1):

This way works with Parse SDK 1.3.0:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getConfig", function(request, response) {
    var config_name = request.params.config_name;
    Parse.Config.get().then(function(config) { 
        console.log(config.get(config_name));
    }).then(function() {
        response.success('Success');
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think they just did not implement Parse.Config in CloudCode right now. Your code seem correct to me. I tested it myself and came to the same problem.

Comment: Ran into the same issue just now. Any idea if this got supported since?